# Is there an edible version of nylon string?

Tags: organic-chemistry, food-chemistry

I'm working on a project where I have to check the feasibility for product ideas. It has to connect other parts and float on the water's surface.

My friend thought that maybe glass noodles would be thin and transparent enough to work in this product. Maybe there is another option that maybe is even water-soluble.

I also looked at PVA, but I don't think it is edible.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: A search of "bioplastics" may find what you are looking for

Comment: Ok, I've looked a bit. I can't seem to find any information about the edibility of the products. I also didn't find any real strings or threads.

Comment: "Edible" is more or less another word for "biodegradable". And *water soluble* and *high tensile strength" is a contradiction in terms. Spider silk springs to mind, or generally protein fibers, aka. wool.

Comment: Surgical thread made of chitin?